# ajax request not working on AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, model-view-controller

i have a mvc app running on aws EC2 with a load balancer but my ajax call to the controller is not responding.The url is https://examspur.com.

please help have spent a day on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SSL/HTTPS settings and redirections. There is somethings wrong with that steps because when you make a request on `https://www.examspur.com/Account/Login` in the response header appear `http://www.examspur.com/account/login`.

At the same time if you open the homepage `https://examspur.com` and after click on "Login/Register" button that brings you to login page you can see that https protocol disappear.